# Ubuntu install previous version of erlang solutions package

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, fabric, apt

I am trying to create a fabric script that will install the erlang solutions R15B02 package and am having some difficulty. I have the following code in my fabric script:

```
sudo("apt-get update")
    sudo("apt-get -qy install python-software-properties")
    sudo('add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian quantal contrib"')
    sudo('add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian precise contrib"')
    sudo('add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian oneiric contrib"')
    sudo('add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian lucid contrib"')
    sudo("wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian/erlang_solutions.asc")
    sudo("sudo apt-key add erlang_solutions.asc")
    sudo("apt-get update")
    sudo("apt-get -qy install ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fontconfig fontconfig-config hicolor-icon-theme icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm java-common libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libice6 libjasper1 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libllvm3.0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-1d liborc-0.4-0 libpango1.0-0 libpixman-1-0 libsm6 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff4 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxxf86vm1 openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib shared-mime-info ttf-dejavu-core tzdata-java x11-common tzdata")
    sudo("apt-get -qy install erlang")
```

This works wonderful for installing 16B but, one of the applications I need to install on these servers has some incompatabilities with 16B currently. Is there a way that I can specify the R15B02 package? When I run apt-cache showpkg erlang, I only see packages for 16B and 14B.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use one of these projects for installing and managing different versions of Erlang on the same computer:

- https://github.com/spawngrid/kerl
- https://github.com/metadave/erln8

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the file 'esl-erlang_15.b.2-1~ubuntu~precise_i386.deb' or the 64 bit version, those could be installed with dpkg. If you find these, to install both at once, extract the .deb with `dpkg -x esl-erlang_15.b.2-1~ubuntu~precise_i386.deb` and move the binaries inside somewhere else. If you can't find that .deb file, you can download the source and compile it, configuring it to install somewhere different with `./configure --prefix=/path/to/old/lib/install/path`.

You could put the old version in a different directory and call it with the variable `LD_PRELOAD` set to, for example, `/usr/old/path/to/old/version/of/erlang/SharedObjectFile.so`.

So to run the program that takes the old version, do this:

`~$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/old/path/to/old/version/of/erlang/oldErlangLib.so ProgramToRun`

I hope this is what you meant. Every time you run the program with the old depencencies this variable will have to be set. You can also set multiple preloads with a space between the libraries to override. Be sure to escape these spaces with double quotes or `\(space character goes here)`.